# Two apps with few changes – Google Play and Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-play, reusability

I want to develop two (or more) apps to publish on Google Play where there are very few differences between them. As an example, consider one app that has fish recipes and a second app that has chicken recipes.

Technically all that would be different is a few string values and a different database (same format) loaded as an asset.

It seems that separate apps must have separate file structures to be compatible with Google Play. In this example that could be [www.mywork.fish](http://www.mywork.fish) and [www.mywork.chicken](http://www.mywork.chicken). This is in addition to having a separate google-services.json file.

If I do this for my Kotlin app in Android Studio I end up with two separate sets of files and all of the import statements also have to change. I had hoped for a common directory with just a few components swapped.

What is best practice for handling such situations of common code?

Comment: Read up about build *flavors*.

Comment: Use Flavors. You can have multiple projects with one source code..